# ¿Cómo imprimir en la Shell de Linux los datos de un archivo CSV en base al número de dígitos que tengan, sin usar sed ni awk?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, línea-de-comandos

Tengo un archivo CSV con dos columnas, una perteneciente a los europarlamentarios y otra a sus identificadores. Estos identificadores tienen entre 3 y 6 números, y me gustaría imprimir por pantalla aquellos parlamentarios junto a sus identificadores, siempre y cuando estos sean de 4 dígitos. Paso a poner los primeros datos del CSV impresos por pantalla que se obtienen mediante el siguiente comando que he utilizado para que se entienda mejor:

`cat europarlamentarios.csv | cut -d "," -f1,2 | head -10`

```
Uma AALTONEN,23752
Damien ABAD,96850
Claudette ABELA BALDACCHINO,118860
Jean-Pierre ABELIN,1829
Victor ABENS,1802
William ABITBOL,4361
Carlos ABOIM INGLEZ,1680
Gérard d'ABOVILLE,2202
Lars ADAKTUSSON,124990
Gordon J. ADAM,1427
```

Como se puede ver, el segundo valor corresponde a los identificadores, y estos tienen diferentes dígitos. Pues bien, me gustaría imprimir por pantalla aquellos nombres de europarlamentarios con sus respectivos identificadores si estos tienen solo 4 dígitos. He probado a utilizar el comando `cut` pero no he sabido como aplicarlo en este caso ya que todas las líneas tienen distinta longitud. También he pensado que igual sería necesario aplicar estructuras de control como por ejemplo `if\else`, pero esto aún se escapa de mis conocimientos ya que estoy empezando a programar, y creo que debe haber alguna manera para sacar el resultado que quiero sin utilizar esta estructura de control.

Si alguien tiene idea de cómo podría hacerse y me echa un cable lo agradezco!!!

Comment: Y qué te molestó de sed y awk, que tan útiles son? :) Ya en serio, es estricto el requerimiento de no usarlos?

Comment: Es que no me está permitido utilizarlos en el ejercicio. Son ejercicios hechos a mala fe jajajaja Es broma, realmente quieren que aprendamos primero a resolver cuestiones sin utilizarlos para no recurrir siempre a ellos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución es usar egrep para encontrar los que tengan ese patrón

```
cat pepe.csv | cut -d "," -f1,2 | egrep ',.{4}$' | head -10
```

Busca después de una coma, los que tengan  4 caracteres en el segundo campo. Cuando se busca un patrón, esos valores entre corchetes suelen indicar la longitud mínima y máxima (y si es un sólo número, representa ambos).

Fíjate en el carácter `$` al final, que indica que va a buscar esa coincidencia al final de cada línea. Para futuros casos, si usas cadenas con otra cosa después del patrón que estás revisando, debes tener esto en cuenta (digamos `PEPITO,1234,OtraCosa`).

La salida es:

```
$ cat pepe.csv | cut -d "," -f1,2 | egrep ',.{4}$' | head -10
Jean-Pierre ABELIN,1829
Victor ABENS,1802
William ABITBOL,4361
Carlos ABOIM INGLEZ,1680
Gérard d'ABOVILLE,2202
Gordon J. ADAM,1427
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder :-) Acabo de utilizar el comando que indicó y es verdad que funciona. Lo que pasa es que también me devuelve aquellos identificadores de 3 dígitos. ¿Habría alguna forma de desechar estos de menos de 4 dígitos?

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta... la cambié al final porque pensé que necesitabas de hasta 4

Comment: Genial, me ha servido. Gracias!!! Muchas gracias también por la explicación. Buscaré más información sobre `egrep` para ver como funciona por si necesito utilizarlo más adelante. Saludos!!

Answer (score 2):

Solo con `bash` podrías hacer algo así:

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2; 
do
  if [ "${#col2}" -eq 4 ]; then echo "$col1, $col2"; fi
done < europarlamentarios.csv
```

Comentarios:

- Seteamos el Input Field Separators como la coma (`IFS=,`)
- Hacemos un ciclo de lectura del archivo de entrada y por cada línea:

  - Verificamos la longitud de la segunda columna `"${#col2}"`
  - Si es igual a 4 (`if [ "${#col2}" -eq 4 ]`) imprimimos la línea

Comment: buena respuesta. También puedes hacerlo más idiomatico con `[[ "${#col2}" -eq 4 ] && echo "$col1, $col2"`

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo una respuesta de un sólo comando con la extensión de `grep` que permite las expresione regulares tipo PERL.

```
$ grep -P '.*?,\d{4}$' europarlamentarios.csv
```

El cual resulta:

```
Jean-Pierre ABELIN,1829
Victor ABENS,1802
William ABITBOL,4361
Carlos ABOIM INGLEZ,1680
Gérard d'ABOVILLE,2202
Gordon J. ADAM,1427
```

En este caso, la expresión regular `'.*?,\d{4}$'` indica:

- `.*?`, todos los caracteres sin ser greedy
- `,`, seguidos de una coma
- `\d{4}`, inmediatamente seguidos de cuatro dígitos
- `$`, luego terminando con un final de línea

Comment: con `-E` hay suficiente, no hace falta cargar el módulo de Perl para las regex. Y de hecho `.*?` diría que es innecesario, con `.*` ya se valida bien